# How do I validate a URL such as "http://mylocalhost:port "in Java?

Tags: java, string, url

I want to validate that a URL entered by a user in a given server must be in this format. for example `http://localhost:port` only. If the URL port is followed by any other strings or anything like this "http://localhost:port/anything ", it should be regarded as an invalid URL. How can I do this with Regex?
I have tried this:

```
public boolean isValidUrl(String url){
    try{
        return new URL(url).toURI();
    }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
        log.info(INVALID_URL_MESSAGE, url)
        return false
    }
}
```

But this allows other strings after the **port** number

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Hint: You need to make sure only numerical values `[0-9]` are found after `:`

Comment: maybe instantiate an URL https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html then check the parts using the available methods

Comment: @ScaryWombat  I don't understand what you mean , please

Comment: see my answer.  But check the javadocs as well.

Comment: Why use regular expressions? The `URL` class already has the methods you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test by looking at the result of the methods on the URL

```
public boolean isValidUrl(String url){
    try{
        URL myURL = new URL(url);
        // only return true if path and query bits are empty
        return myURL.getPath() == null && myURL.getQuery() == null;
    }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
        log.info(INVALID_URL_MESSAGE, url)
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. But I had to change the **getPath() != null** for it to give me exactly what I wanted.